# imagick pseudostring format

Tags: php, imagemagick, imagick

I'm putting together an image handler in Imagick - I've looked at the pseudoimage class:

```
$test->newPseudoImage($width, $height, $pseudostring);
```

However I can't find a breakdown of what pseudostring can contain - does anyone know a good one?

and I'm making use of setOption:

```
$text->setOption('fill', $fontColour[$_POST['fontColour']]);
```

but I can't find a clear explanation of how this maps to (I assume) Image Magick's own variables.

I have searched here and Google, all I need is a clear breakdown - can anyone point me to one?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Pseudo Format

ImageMagick's [pseudo format](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/formats.php#pseudo) can be defined as "format:[argument]". Each format will have it's own unique effects/behavior, and cover a range of image properties (e.g. **label:**"Hello World!") to specific OS actions (e.g. **x:***root*). There are also built-in images that can be accessed through the pseudo format.

Examples:

```php
$img = new ImageMagick();
$img->newPseudoImage(75,50,'label:"Hello World!"');
$img->writeImage('hello.png');
```

[image: Hello World!]

```php
$img = new ImageMagick();
$img->newPseudoImage(75,50,'pattern:BRICKS');
$img->writeImage('bricks.png');
```

[image: Bricks!]

### Set Option

`Imagick::setOption` sets a key / value options directly on the C-API Wand library (see [MagickSetOption](http://www.imagemagick.org/api/magick-property.php#MagickSetOption)). Set option in Wand would translate to the [-define](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/command-line-options.php#define) argument in ImageMagick script's command-line-options.

### Documentation

> ... I can't find a clear explanation of how this maps to (I assume) Image Magick's own variables.
>   I have searched here and Google, all I need is a clear breakdown - can anyone point me to one?

For the most part, ImageMagick ships with detailed documentation, manuals, and examples. Although such articles can be found online, you may need to refer to the documentation that shipped with your current install.

Comment: And there's the problem - ideally I'd like to send a chain of parameters in the pseudostring, but so far everything I've read has indicated that you can only pass one. I had hoped that the pseudostring would simply be a normal set of Image Magick command line parameters, but that doesn't appear to be the case sadly.  Fortunately imagick has a good selection of getters and setters, but it would be cleaner (for me) to send everything across in a single parameter string.
Good answer though, thank you, well worth my vote.